confusing `rm` command corner behavior
I am trying to understand the corner case behaviors of rm command. In a folder owned and grouped by root, I have a file owned by user alice. However, user alice does not have any permissions on the file and containing folder is owner and grouped by root. (here I use the term grouped, meaning that it belongs to that group)
There are three scenarios when trying to remove the file based on other's permission bits of the folder.
Scenario 1: others have read and write permission. In this case, rm command removes the file with a prompt:
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ sudo ls -alFh
total 0
drwx----wx 1 root  root  4.0K Dec 10 15:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 alice alice 4.0K Dec 10 14:39 ../
---------- 1 alice alice    0 Dec 10 15:14 foo
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ rm foo
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'foo'? yes
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ sudo ls -alFh
total 0
drwx----wx 1 root  root  4.0K Dec 10 15:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 alice alice 4.0K Dec 10 14:39 ../
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$

In the case that the other's permission bits is only execute, then we have the following behavior:
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ rm foo
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file 'foo'? yes
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Permission denied
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ sudo ls -alFh
total 0
drwx-----x 1 root  root  4.0K Dec 10 15:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 alice alice 4.0K Dec 10 14:39 ../
---------- 1 alice alice    0 Dec 10 15:14 foo

Now in the case that other's permission bits of the folder is only read, then here is the behavior:
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ rm foo
rm: cannot remove 'foo': Permission denied
alice@cherry:.../folder_root$ sudo ls -la
total 0
drwx----w- 1 root  root  4096 Dec 10 15:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 alice alice 4096 Dec 10 14:39 ..
---------- 1 alice alice    0 Dec 10 15:14 foo

I guess I don't understand why the read and execute permission bits are required to remove the file. Why is this the behavior?

This is SuperUser Meta, not SuperUser itself. Let an appropriate community member migrate your question.
